# please spot the error its working in dev but not in hackerrank

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, c++14

code is not working in hackerrank but working in dev c++??
the output value is 1047095560 some number like this ive tried other ways to solve code and its working but this approach is not working. some of the test cases are
10 3
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
ans 10
second test case
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
ans 200

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,m,ans;
cin>>n>>m;
int a[m][3],b[n]={0};
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
     cin>>a[i][j];
}

for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
{
    for(int i=a[k][0];i<=a[k][1];i++)
    {
         b[i-1]+=a[k][2];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{  
   if(b[i]>b[i+1])
    {   
         ans=b[i];
         swap(b[i],b[i+1]);
    }
    else
          ans=b[i+1];
}
cout<<ans;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should remove the `;` after `#include <iostream>`

Comment: `int a[m][3],b[n]={0};` are variable-length arrays and not standard C++. It's a compiler specific extension. You should avoid it to make your code portable. It could cause such problems that your code works on some machines and doesn't work on other machines..

Comment: Even with the compiler extension, large inputs will cause a stack overflow. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Please describe what the program is supposed to accomplish. Two vague test cases is not a problem description.

Comment: What does "_ans_" mean? First I though it was a typo - but it's written twice.

Comment: You can replace the third loop with `ans = *std::max_element(std::begin(b), std::end(b));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from a typo in your very first line (a semi-colon after include directive) and using non-standard VLAs, the main bug was your third loop which was resulting in a garbage value. You should change the check statement from `i < n` to `i < n - 1`.

Here is a more portable and compact version, which shall support all compilers (C++14 and above):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(m, std::vector<int>(3, 0));
    std::vector<int> b(n, 0);
    for (auto &i : a)
        for (auto &j : i)
            std::cin >> j;
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        for (int i = a[k][0]; i <= a[k][1]; i++)
            b[i - 1] += a[k][2];
    std::cout << *std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

Sample Input 1:

```
10 3
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
```

Sample Output 1:

```
10
```

Sample Input 2:

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

Sample Output 2:

```
200
```

Answer (score 3):

One issue is in:

```
int b[n]={0};
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{  
   if(b[i]>b[i+1])
   ...
}
```

In the last iteration, when `i == n - 1`, accessing `b[i+1]` yields undefined behavior.